# How to return from a static initialization block in java

Tags: java, static, initialization

I want to return from the static block.

Looks like the return and break statement don't work. Is there any alternative.

I know the bad workaround could be create a flag and check the flag to continue or not.

I understand that the initialisation blocks are not meant for doing computations but just for basic initialisation during class loading.

Comment: please provide your source code

Comment: I can't understand the problem. Please explain it clearly or provide your code for easy understanding.

Comment: @Kalai I suppose he means that `return` can not be used within an initializer block. JLS 14.17: "[...] It is a compile-time error if a return statement is contained in an instance initializer or a static initializer [...]"

Answer (score 20):

Delegate the code to a private static method:

```
static {
    initialize();
}

private static void initialize() {
    foo();
    if (someCondition) {
        return;
    }
    bar();
}
```

Comment: cleaner way to write inialize blocks.

Comment: can't assign `static final` field this way

Comment: @wilmol Sure you can :) Either use `private static final Singleton INSTANCE = initialize();` or `static { INSTANCE = initialize(); }`.

Answer (score 7):

Instead of using `return` just wrap your conditional code in an `if`.

Answer (score 5):

Static initialisers have no business being complicated, so it's probably a bad idea (even if you don't buy SESE).

The minimal way of achieving a return is to use a labelled break.

```
static {
    init: {
        ...
           break init;
    }
}
```

They are quite rare, typically appearing in nested `for` loops. The novelty might tip off the reader that something a bit dodgy is going on.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot return from a static initializer block.  There is nowhere to return to.  But it shouldn't be necessary.  You should be able to restructure your code to be "single entry, single exit".

Comment: I would have to agree with this statement, it would also provide much cleaner (and easier to read) code.

Answer (score 0):

You can not return from static block but better to use some other function that will perform your logic and return to the block.