# How to initialise a static final class member of type ObjectName?

Tags: java, jmx

The following code does not compile ("variable name might not have been initialized"):

```
import javax.management.*;

public class Main {
    public final static ObjectName name;
    static {
        try {
            name = new ObjectName("abc");
        } catch (final Exception e) {
            System.exit(1);
        }   
    }   
}
```

However, the following code does not compile either ("variable name might already have been assigned"):

```
import javax.management.*;

public class Main {
    public final static ObjectName name;
    static {
        try {
            name = new ObjectName("abc");
        } catch (final Exception e) {
            name = null;
            System.exit(1);
        }   
    }   
}
```

I do not think the compiler is right about the either case, but anyways how are we supposed to initialize a static final ObjectName?

Comment: I think.when you use final, then it should be inititalised when you declare itself. Kindly try this logic and tell whether still you get error

Comment: Why would the `ObjectName` constructor throw an exception anyway? That's a code smell right there.

Comment: @DanTemple It is perfectly legal for a constructor to throw an exception. The code smell is something else here.

Answer (score 1):

The first line of advice is *don't call `System.exit()`*. It causes the application to suddenly quit, without normal cleanup.

If you absolutely must exit the application at that precise point, then your workaround is to add

```
throw e;
```

after your `System.exit()` call.

If you're curious about the compiler error, you may be interested to read about it in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17075061/could-a-final-variable-be-reassigned-in-catch-even-if-assignment-is-last-operat).

Answer (score 1):

The compiler expects that, *in all possible branches of execution* within your static initializer block, that `ObjectName` is assigned a value.

In

```
static {
    try {
        name = new ObjectName("abc");
    } catch (final Exception e) {
        System.exit(1);
    }   
}
```

Since `ObjectName` is not assigned a value in the catch-block, ***and*** since no exception is thrown, the compiler does not allow it.

If there were an exception thrown in the catch block, it would be acceptable.

An [alternative method](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11118263/2736496) to implementing static initializer blocks, which I prefer, is where the block is a simple call to a private static function:

```
static  {
   init();
}
   private static init()  {
      //do stuff
   }
```

Answer (score 0):

Just use a private static method instead of the static initializer:

```
private static final ObjectName name = initObjectName();

private static ObjectName initObjectName() {
   try {
      return new ObjectName("abc");
   } catch (MalformedObjectNameException e) {
      return null;
   }
}
```