# Java - can we return from within an initializer?

Tags: java, jls

Why there cannot be multiple exit points from a static initializer? Does Java Language specification state so?

When trying to compile code as:

```
class HelloWorldApp {
    static {
        if(1 > 2)
          return;
        System.out.println("static"); 
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        System.out.println("Hello World!"); 
    }
}
```

Compiler prints out an error: `return outside method`

Java disassembly with `javap` shows that `static` is a void method, so would it be possible, theoretically, to create a bytecode that would have multiple 'returns'?

Comment: The JLS states that a `return` statement within a `static` initializer is illegal [here](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-8.html#jls-8.7).

Comment: This looks like a JVM question, not a JLS one.  The too specs do differ at times, and this may be one of them.

Comment: see at : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11118226/how-to-return-from-a-static-initialization-block-in-java

Comment: @SotiriosDelimanolis turn that into an answer, so I can accept it

Comment: @Axarydax I do not recall anything in the JVM spec that prohibits that (obviously there is in the JLS spec).  Probably the best way to find out would be to try it.  You could use a jvm assembler tool like http://jasmin.sourceforge.net/

Comment: @ChrisK How isn't it a JLS question? The JVM supports stuff not in Java.

Comment: @DaveNewton from the question 'so would it be possible, theoretically, to create a bytecode'... the JVM is capable of doing some things that the JLS does not allow, such as having return type as part of the method signature.  Perhaps the OP could clarify.

Comment: @ChrisK I was able to create the .class file with Jasmin, thanks, so it runs in JVM without problems. That makes me wondering why would the return statement be forbidden in the JLS.

Comment: @ChrisK That's my point; the JVM supports functionality not available at the Java level.

Comment: @ChrisK "there is no caller to return to"  Depends whether you think this is a question about the language or, about the implementation.  (nobody on this thread seems to know).  There _is_ a caller, but like you said, it's not any method in the program's source code.

Answer (score 5):

The JLS states that a `return` statement within a `static` initializer is illegal [here](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-8.html#jls-8.7).